# show jQuery.validationEngine alerts only after submit

Tags: jquery

I use [jQuery.validationEngine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) plugin and i want to show alerts only after the user submit the form not while editing the form.

Example:

```
<form id="formID" method="post" action="submit.action">
<input value="2010-12-01" class="validate[required,custom[date]]" type="text" name="date" id="date" />
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#formID").validationEngine();
 });
```

I know that this is might be easy but i'm new to $.

Comment: You probably don't want an inline form validator for this.

Comment: @Jivings - I have a big form and this is just an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validation engine does this.. set the "binded" option to true.  ex:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#formID").validationEngine('attach', {
        binded: TRUE
   });
 });
```

https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

According to the docs, the above should work.  Since it doesn't try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#formbutton").click(function(){
        $("#form").validationEngine().submit();
        $("#form").validationEngine('detach');
    });
});
```

Make the validationengine attach on the button submit.  If it fails you detach to get rid of inline edits.

Comment: Thanks James, this works great but the alerts still show while editing.

Comment: binded is supposed to turn off validation until you submit, I thought that was what you were trying to achieve.  Do you mean that the validation is still occurring inline, or the validation messages continue to appear when you edit the flagged field after submit?

Comment: What i want to achieve is to disable the validation messages before submit. So the validation done and show any messages after submit. not while editing.

Comment: Yes the validation is still occurring inline.

Comment: Thanks so much James, you really saved my life. It works without 'detach'

Answer (score 0):

Validation engine does this.. set the "binded" option to false.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#formID").validationEngine({
    binded: false
   });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way i do it  (With AJAX Login)

```
$("#loginModal form").validationEngine('attach', {
  autoHidePrompt: true,
  autoHideDelay: 3000,
  validationEventTrigger: 'submit',// Validate on Submit
  onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
    if(status) { // status == true == it validated!!!
        // Login With Ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: '/login',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                email: $('#login-email').val(),
                password: $('#login-password').val(),
            },
            success: function( result ) {
                   // Your Success func.
            }
        });
    }
  }
});
```